# How to find sum of column in Ireport or jasper report?

Tags: java, printing, jasper-reports, ireport

I have column in detail band with value

> $F{thScore}+$F{prScore}

I would like to find the sum of this column in run time . How is this possible in jasper report using Ireport.
I did it with variable but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable is defined and

> variable expression

to

> $F{thScore}+$F{prScore}

and

> calculation

to

> sum

.It worked for me where $F{thScore},$F{prScore} are fields in detail band.

Comment: Is using variables the only way to sum up columns? Even in tables? If I have 30 columns, do I have to manually set up 30 separate variables??

Answer (score 1):

I had a fields of Integer type and was trying to add the columns . I was not getting any error when the report is previewed but my java application was failing to compile the report and giving the error as

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer value =
>   (java.lang.Integer)(((java.lang.Integer)field_nBSRptSchm1Col1.getValue())+((java.lang.Integer)field_nBSRptSchm2Col1.getValue()));
>   //$JR_EXPR_ID=8$

then I used the following code to add the columns of Integer type...

```
new Integer($F{nSchm1Col1}.intValue() + $F{Schm2Col1}.intValue() )
```

where `nSchm1Col1` and `Schm2col1` are two fields which I want to add. This one worked for me